# How to make swap(random) positions between 3 objects by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
//array
var boxs: Array = new Array 
boxs[0] = [b1.x = 307.95  , b1.y = 202]
boxs[1] = [b2.x = 233.95  ,  b2.y = 202]
boxs[2] = [b3.x = 159.95  ,  b3.y = 202]

//varable 
var oldg:Number = 0
//random number
oldg = Number(Math.floor(Math.random()*boxs.length))
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach:

```
    public function Main()
    {
        const array:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
        trace(array);
        // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
        swapTwoRandomElements(array);
        trace(array);
        // 1,2,3,6,5,4,7
    }

    private function swapTwoRandomElements(input:Array):void
    {
        const indices:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            indices.push(i);
        }
        const indexFirst:int = indices[int(Math.random() * indices.length)];
        indices.splice(indexFirst, 1);
        const indexSecond:int = indices[int(Math.random() * indices.length)];
        indices.splice(indexSecond, 1);

        const tmp:* = input[indexFirst];
        input[indexFirst] = input[indexSecond];
        input[indexSecond] = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Where is X Y position

Comment: @ActionScriptstudent Can you please edit your question then? It's not clear  what do you mean under the question "where is X Y position". According to the general question, you wanted to swap two random positions in an array. In your code example you create an array of arrays of numbers, there are no X or Y coordinates there. If you want to use the swapping function with your boxs array, just make a call: `swapTwoRandomElements(boxs);`

Comment: @ActionScriptstudent The simplest way is to define initial positions as an array of points: `const positions:Array = [new Point(20, 20),...etc.]`. Then just use the swapping function for shuffling this array. After the positions array is rearranged, you need to apply this positions to your clips in appropriate order. For animation you can use some package like TweenLite.

Comment: @ActionScriptstudent I believe it's a wrong place to ask for this. I suggest going to https://www.upwork.com/